# Bootstrap grid system; button placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place a button where I want it, using the Bootstrap grid system, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I currently have:

[image: current]

I would like the button to be **at the far right** of the page and **at the same height as the title**. How can I do this?

My code is the following:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row marketing'>
    <div class='col-lg-15'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-10'>
                    <div class='media'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                             <h1 class='media-heading'>
                             Title
                                 <small>Subtitle</small>
                             </h1>
                             <h5>Additional text</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2'>
                    <button class='btn'>Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Page Content:</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/urzyLo6r/1/

Comment: you can just remove the second row and put them in the same row. and add pull right to the button's div.

Comment: You are missing your grid col styles..

Comment: @wrick17 Placing them in the same row worked for me!

Comment: that's the first thing , rows clear floats ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just messed up yours rows and columns. If you want everything in one row, you simply do not create another row for your button (this will put it below your first row). Just image it like a table. Another thing is, that if you use some h tags, they have some spacing, so if you still put everything in one row it will almost work, but as you mention in comment your button will be in line with "additional text". So you have to put button above your h1 tag, give it class "pull-right" and delete class row on div with button. Here is what works for me in fiddle:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row marketing'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2 pull-right'>
                    <button class='btn'>Button</button>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-10 pull-left'>
                    <div class='media'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                             <h1 class='media-heading'>
                            Title
                            <small>Subtitle</small>
                        </h1>

                             <h5>Additional text</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
        <h3>Page Content:</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And just for future, bootstrap used 12 column grid, so there is no reason to use col-lg-15. Well, at least if you didn't edit bootstrap files itself.

Comment: I just realize I forgot something. My answer  is not responsive as bootstrap should be, but there is realy simple solution for that. Just add pull-left class to div with col-md-10, then the titles will not hide behind button on small screens. I edited my answer, so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

the fiddle is not bringing them in one line because u have col-md. as the screen width is less. try col-xs..

try this:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row marketing'>
    <div class='col-lg-15'>
        <div class='page-header'>

            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-10'>
                    <div class='media'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                             <h1 class='media-heading'>
                            Title
                            <small>Subtitle</small>
                        </h1>

                             <h5>Additional text</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xs-2'>
                    <button class='btn pull-right'>Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Page Content:</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add pull-right class to your button :

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row marketing'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-10'>
                    <div class='media'>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                             <h1 class='media-heading'>
                            Title
                            <small>Subtitle</small>
                        </h1>

                             <h5>Additional text</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button class='btn pull-right'>Button</button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Page Content:</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts it at the far right, but not at the same height as the Title.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have your columns defined in the Bootstrap grid,

and by default the browser's UserAgent defines divs with `display:block` so it automatically clears floats;

just to try I changed your divs in `display:inline-block` and here's [the result](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/urzyLo6r/2/):

BTW you need to see why your col are not defined, you can't use this as a fix , it's just to show the problem.